# uninstalling logstash with remove is not working on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, logstash

I just installed elasticsearch, kibana and logstash on ubuntu. Then I decided to uninstall them with this command:

sudo apt-get autoremove package-name
and for elasticsearch and kibana I successfully uninstalled them, but for logstash after two hours it just showing:

"Removing logstash (1:7.13.2-1) ..."

nothing more.

Comment: Just use ‘remove’ (or ‘purge’), not autoremove

Comment: And maybe consult the docs for autoremove - it’s doesn’t work the way you think

Comment: I did that too but doesn't help

Comment: Maybe ask on https://askubuntu.com/?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. The other solutions didn't work for me, so here is what I did:

```
sudo pkill -9 -u logstash`
sudo apt remove logstash`
```

For some reason if I ran `sudo systemctl stop logstash.service` the system wouldn't respond.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot in net I find out that the problem was that Logstash service didn't stop correctly so this is what I have done:

1. I restart my laptop
2. I stopped logstash with: "sudo systemctl stop logstash.service"
3. I ran this command to remove logstash: "sudo apt-get remove logstash"

I hope it will help others